# recurrence relation for the number of sequences of digits

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I want to find a recurrence relation for the number of sequences of digits $(1, 2, 3)$ with a sum of digits equal to n which don’t contain sub-sequnce $123\ldots$.

I tried out the first seven cases for $n$ and found no patterns at all where $n=1$ has only $1$, $n=2$ has $11$ and $2$, $n=3$ has $111, 12, 21, 3$,
and so on...

Comment: To state the obvious:  your examples are too small.  The condition on $123$ doesn't signify until $n=6$, for $n=6$ you are only ruling out one sequence, annd for $n=7$ you are only ruling out two sequences.

Comment: Hi, I was thinking first find the recurrence relation for the number of sequences of digits (1, 2, 3) with a sum of digits equal to n which is the first part and then subtracted by the second part: the number of  sub-sequnce ..123... However, I was unable to find the relation even for the first one. Can you provide any hint for that please? thank you!

Comment: Well, first it really is important to generate examples.  Else, how could you tell if your recursion was correct or not?

Comment: As to the recursion, I'd split into types.  Look for good sequences that end in $1$, those that end in $12$ and those that end in $X$ where $X$ is either $3$, $22$ or $32$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that the total number of sequence which does not contain subgroup $123$ is $a_n$.Then , we know that the end of the sequence will end up with either $1$ or $2$ or $3$.

Let $a_{n-1}$ be the sequence which end up with $1$ and does not contain subsequence $123$

Let $a_{n-1}$ be the sequence which end up with $2$ and does not contain subsequence $123$

Let $a_{n-1}$ be the sequence which end up with $3$ and does not contain subsequence $123$

So , there are total $3 \times a_{n-1}$ such sequence but realize that when we construct the sequence which end up with $3$ , it may have $12$ in front of $3$ and remember that it does not contain the subsequence $123$. That is , $.....12$ $ \cup$ $3$ where $.....12$ does not contain any subgroup that contain $123$.However ,when we merge these two part , it will contain the subgroup $123$ , so we should subtract it from the first formula.

$\therefore a_n= (3 \times a_{n-1})-a_{n-3}$

Comment: @MSquare Is there anywhere you did not understand

Comment: Thank you so much! This is pretty clear now